# How to resolve this issue? cannot just understand , I tried to import it by install but still not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to importing

```
fethcer . py file from 

src/fetcher/entrypoints/fethcer.py

to tests/steps/step_impl.py file
```

how can i import that?

```
...src.fetcher.entrypoints.fetcher import *
```

but it's giving me error

from ...src.fetcher.entrypoints.fetcher import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

then what is the way?

dependency graph is -

```
 .
    ├── fetcher.db
    ├── README.MD
    ├── src
    │   └── fetcher
    │       ├── entrypoints
    │       │   ├── fetcher.py
    │       │   ├── __init__.py
    │       │   └── __pycache__
    │       │       
    │       │   
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── __pycache__
    │           
    └── tests
        ├── acceptance
        │   └── fetch_relevant_instrument_list.feature
        ├── environment.py
        └── steps
            └── steps_impl.py
```

Comment: from fetcher import fetcher.entrypoints

Comment: it's giving me syntax error , after that fethcer.entrypoints as .

Comment: Can you share the error

Comment: from fetcher import fetcher.entrypoints
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: getting error at the position (.)....... i am trying to access fetcher.py file from steps_impl.py both are in very deep file structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

steps_impl will have following line:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, r'path/to/the/application/')
from src.fetcher.fetcher import func1
```

I tried to recreate your folder structure:

```
D:.
├───src
│   ├───fetcher
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └───__init__.py
│   │   └───fetcher.py
│   ├───__pycache__
│   └───__init__.py
└───tests
    ├───acceptance
    └───steps
        └───steps_impl.py
```

I refered this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder).

Comment: Where i need to add those lines ? inside fetcher.py? or steps_impl.py? or __init__.py? or i have to install it by creating a setup.py file?..... I am trying to importing fecher.py inside steps_impl.py , so shall i need tho add those lines in fetcher.py file? and there won't be 1 there needs to be 2 or 3

Comment: and it also giving me error no module name src

Comment: add _ _ init _ _.py in src folder as well